# app engine issue for java with frontend instances in production and blocking requests

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, objectify

My website is **sometimes** getting blocked and not working every few time (other times it works fine for a long while, with the same code), getting the log I show below. Each time this happens, I have to go to my console, refresh the cache, and change in application settings the Frontend Instance Class from F1 to F2 or F4 to make possible the first loading, and once it´s done, changing back to F1 (which works perfectly after the first request). But after a while, I got again the server error and my website doesn´t work.

```
...Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36" ms=60615 cpu_ms=41418 loading_request=1 exit_code=104 app_engine_release=1.8.4 instance=00c61b117cd6a25994d15ffe59bc99e20e5cb2bb
    I 2013-09-06 17:06:12.201
    javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    I 2013-09-06 17:06:50.336
    javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
    E 2013-09-06 17:07:03.075
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/base/data/home/apps/s~comprarebookhoy/1.370036978402952713/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-4.0b2.jar!/com/googlecode/objectify/repackaged/gentyref/CaptureType.class]; nested exception is com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (1de39e8e35c0b3f7) started at 2013/09/07 00:06:03.615 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/07 00:07:03.073 UTC.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:261)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:514)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.**initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:455)**
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.**DeadlineExceededException: **This request (1de39e8e35c0b3f7) started at 2013/09/07 00:06:03.615 UTC and was still executing at** 2013/09/07 00:07:03.073 UTC.**
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:209)
        at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:285)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:217)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:156)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:88)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:125)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
        ... 48 more
    E 2013-09-06 17:07:03.077
    javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/base/data/home/apps/s~comprarebookhoy/1.370036978402952713/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-4.0b2.jar!/com/googlecode/objectify/repackaged/gentyref/CaptureType.class]; nested exception is com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (1de39e8e35c0b3f7) started at 2013/09/07 00:06:03.615 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/07 00:07:03.073 UTC.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:261)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1421)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:638)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:595)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:514)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:455)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (1de39e8e35c0b3f7) started at 2013/09/07 00:06:03.615 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/07 00:07:03.073 UTC.
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:209)
        at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:285)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:217)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:156)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:153)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:88)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:125)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
        ... 48 more
    W 2013-09-06 17:07:03.122
    (my url)
    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: **The API call memcache.Get() was explicitly cancelled**.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:268)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Get() was explicitly cancelled.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:386)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:383)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:28)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:51)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:36)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:327)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:301)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:237)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.setRequestedId(SessionHandler.java:246)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
        ... 16 more
    W 2013-09-06 17:07:03.123
    Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Get() was explicitly cancelled.:
    com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Get() was explicitly cancelled.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:386)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$5.get(ApiProxyImpl.java:383)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:28)
        at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:51)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.MemcacheSessionStore.getSession(MemcacheSessionStore.java:36)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.loadSession(SessionManager.java:327)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:301)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.AbstractSessionManager.getHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:237)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.setRequestedId(SessionHandler.java:246)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:136)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    I 2013-09-06 17:07:03.131
    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
    W 2013-09-06 17:07:03.131
    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)
```

In my local environment I don´t get this problem. Looks like some kind of issues between the spring framework and the cache used by gae, but no idea what´s going on here... any suggestions please?

It also looks to be related with the front end instances, i think i have always one after the first request, but for some reason, at some moments goes shutdown and i have to change again to the F4 option to make it work, otherwise I got server error.

And from the logs, it´s possible objectify is making some kind of exception provoking the issue, i´m using version 4.0b2

I found also a related bug in app engine for the part: `"ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Get() was explicitly cancelled."`

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7107

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your app just takes too long to start. You're hitting the 60s deadline.

It takes 10X longer for your app to start on an F1 than it does on your desktop. In prod, not only is the server loading classes over a slow network, but F1 instances are *really* underpowered - your cellphone has more available CPU.

Your app is just on the edge of hitting the 60s deadline. When you switch to F2/F4 instances, the extra CPU power puts you under the deadline and your app starts. Changing the instance size doesn't immediately resize your instances; it only affects new instances that start up. So when you change back to F1, eventually GAE starts up a new instance and you're back to the same deadline problem.

Note that it's always dangerous to be "on the edge" because GAE performance is erratic. Variance can be up to 3X; it's dangerous to take more than 20-25s to start up.

Unfortunately there's no magic solution to this other than "optimize your startup". Go through it with a profiler. It will not be accurate because running locally does not give you the same behavior as you get server-side (as you've noticed, you don't get the same slowdowns) but it's a start. Avoid eager classloading if you can - although this is tricky with DI frameworks. And make sure to avoid doing any prefetching of data from remote sources (including the datastore or memcache) at startup.

One way you can help mitigate the problem (aside from using F2 or F4 instances) is to create a cron job that pings your app once per second. Cron tasks get a 10m deadline instead of 60s. At the very least, you'll get one instance off the ground.

Answer (score -1):

Well what I can infer from your stacktrace is that there is process which is running inside your appengine application which the call any other process or may be some third party process  and for that the timeout for the execution of the later process exceeds hence you are getting this exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL

**[jar:file:/base/data/home/apps/s~comprarebookhoy/1.370036978402952713/WEB-INF/lib/objectify-4.0b2.jar!/com/googlecode/objectify/repackaged/gentyref/CaptureType.class];**

nested exception is com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: 
This request (1de39e8e35c0b3f7) started at 2013/09/07 00:06:03.615 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/07 00:07:03.073 UTC
```

There is no any problem with **Objectify Library, Spring as well as with Appengine**. It is the problem inside your code which is causing this exception to occur whenever that particular process comes under execution.

Also try to check in your appengine dashboard that what instances of appengine usage is high by your application. Also you can check many more things in your appengine dashboard itself.

Also check the last few lines of your stacktrace. It clearly explains the cause of this error.

```
I 2013-09-06 17:07:03.131
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W 2013-09-06 17:07:03.131
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may be throwing exceptions during the initialization of your application. (Error code 104)
```

Comment: It doesn't explain what's that alleged process which is causing the problem, which it doesn't happen at all in development. There is also a bug in app engine https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7107 not fixed which is happening in my application if you check the logs: ApiProxy$CancelledException: The API call memcache.Set() was explicitly cancelled.